# javascript settimeout takes too much time than expected to excute the code

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to make the code works fine in stackoverflow but when I added the javascript code, it has stopped.any way
I have this code:

```js
showCharacters("hey, how are you");

function showCharacters(text) {
  var charactersArray = new String(text).split('');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {
    setCharacter(i, charactersArray);
  }
  deleteAll(i - 1);
}

function setCharacter(i, charactersArray) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML + charactersArray[i];
  }, 1000 * i);
}

function deleteAll(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML;
    var charactersArray = new String(text).split('');
    var charactersArrayLength = charactersArray.length - 1;
    for (var j = charactersArrayLength; j >= 0; j--) {
      charactersArray.splice(j, 1);
      deleteCharacter(charactersArray.join(""), i + charactersArrayLength - j + 1);
    }
  }, (i + 1) * 1000);
}

function deleteCharacter(text, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = text;
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```

```css
#divContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
#characters {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
  <h1 id="characters">
  </h1>
</div>
```

I made the code to write one character every second and after complete the text it will delete one character every second,the problem is that after complete the text it will wait for a few seconds before starting deleting the characters.I did not do that.

I have followed the time value of settimeout method and everything is fine.

I want it to start deleting characters directly after complete the text.

any help please.

Comment: A couple of general remarks: please use the [Tidy] button when editing a code snippet, it makes the code more readable. Also I'd recommend keeping variable names a bit shorter, e.g. it is very common to use `i` or `j` for indexing, better that than all the text you have now.

Comment: /* After your edit: */ thanks, better

Comment: ooh, thanks for you.you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stayed close to your code, the fix was actually quite simple, I marked it with `THE FIX` below.

```js
// Replace spaces with non-breaking spaces so it does not stutter, and use global var
var text = "hey, how are you".replace(/ /g, String.fromCharCode(160));
showCharacters();

function showCharacters() {
  var chars = new String(text).split('');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    setCharacter(i, chars);
  }
  deleteAll(i - 1);
}

function setCharacter(i, chars) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML + chars[i];
  }, 200 * i);
}

function deleteAll(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var chars = new String(text).split('');
    var len = chars.length - 1;
    for (var j = len; j >= 0; j--) {
      chars.splice(j, 1);
      deleteCharacter(chars.join(""), i - j + 1); // THE FIX: don't add length here
    }
  }, (i + 1) * 200);
}

function deleteCharacter(text, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("characters").innerHTML = text;
  }, 200 * i);
}
```

```css
#divContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
#characters {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
  <h1 id="characters">
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what the parameters inside replace method mean?

Comment: The first part `/ /g` is a very simple Regular Expression that matches spaces, and that will match globally (hence the `g`) to achieve global replace. The second part is what the spaces that we just found will be replaced with, it is a library call to obtain a character with ascii-value 160. In HTML that character is the same as using `&nbsp;` but then with just one character, which is what we need here.

Comment: yes,you are right,thanks a lot.but why this is the reason of that problem (the time problem).? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Dont line up app the timeouts in a row do them one after the other.

Here is how you should do it. I speed the time up a bit, but that matters not.

```js
var text = "Add a new timeout as needed."
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
var textPos = 0;
function textAdd(){
   div.textContent += text[textPos++];
   if(textPos >= text.length){
      setTimeout(clearText,1000);
   }else{
      setTimeout(textAdd,200);
   }
}
function clearText(){
   textPos --;
   div.textContent = text.substr(0,textPos);
   if(textPos === 0){
       setTimeout(textAdd,1000);
   }else{
       setTimeout(clearText,200);
   }
}
textAdd();
```

Comment: I am asking for the reason,not for a good code.
but your code is amazing,and thanks any way.

Comment: @phoenix I looked at your code and could not work out what was wrong without running it and checking the timeouts for the error. You can use the console to show info. If you add just before the timeout `console.log("timeout  Func name "+((i+1)*1000));` Then open the console with F12 you will see the list of times. This will help you track the problem.

Comment: I did it and everything is fine,and I said that in the post.
there is a time(about 8 seconds) between complete the text and starting deleting the characters

Comment: @phoenix  I will have another look.

Comment: @phoenix Your delete function should start at i = 0 when I output the times to the console it starts at 16000 (i = 16) and moves up.

Comment: yes,it will because the time end with 16000 when it complete the text,and I have to start with that time

Comment: @phoenix No you are setting that time only after the text has finished being displayed. The `setTimeout` is time from now. So `setTimeout(func,16000)` is 16000ms from when the setTimeout function is called. You call the second lot of timeouts from the timeout function in `deleteALL` that does not happen until after the text is display. If you add `console.log("timeout"+(i*1000))` you can see in the console when each timeout is being set.

Comment: oh,now I understand,I edited the time to value = 1 but the result is that the text disappear quickly without showing deleting character by character